# Outlook: quickly move item to folder by typing destination name

Tags: microsoft-outlook, productivity, addons

Is there an Outlook method, add-on/plugin or something that duplicates the functionality of Thunderbird [Quick Folder Move](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/quick-folder-move/) extension? It is on my most missed features of Thunderbird, which I can no longer use at my work place.

When activated the quick move extension pops up a dialog where you find the destination by typing. Matching suggestions are shown immediately after each character press. It's very fast and fluid. It can be fired by context menu (r-click) or shortcut key.

I'm aware of Outlook's '[Move to folder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/move-or-copy-an-item-to-another-folder-19768dfe-86c4-40bf-b82c-1c084b624492)' quick step action and the Move to folder button in the Home ribbon (`Alt-H`,`M`,`V`). These work quite well, but only the 10 most recent matches are shown and the folder order changes with every use. Other folders can be gotten to by opening sub-menus, but that requires several more steps.

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut can be found by hovering over the option on the ribbon:
[image]

Or you can add the command to QAT and then use Alt+number as the shortcut key. For instance, in my case, the shortcut is Alt+3:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the QAT route, I didn't think of that, +1.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest route I've located to date using stock Outlook features is the shortcut `Ctrl-Shift-V` and then typing first letter of folder list followed by arrow keys. It's not as fluid as TB Quick Folder Move but still faster than the ribbon button or context menu. 
(It's actually a shortcut to the shortcut `Alt-H`,`M`,`V`,`O`).

*Found by way of [Susan Harkins](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/two-favorite-keyboard-shortcuts-for-keeping-email-organized/) on Tech Republic.*

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Quick Folders](https://www.reliefjet.com/Quicks/Features/QuickFolders) add-in for Outlook that does exactly what you want: allows you to type the part of target folder's name. Works really fast. Please note that I'm one of the developers of this add-in.

Comment: Looks interesting. Perhaps add a bit about it's used in this context, e.g. what key-strokes to move a message to folder X?

Comment: @mattwilkie, it depends on where do you place the QF's "Move to Folder..." button on the ribbon.